# Meshcat Simulator

Tags: drake

I'm simulating a system using MeshcatVisualizer but the simulation happens extremely fast. Is there a way to slow down the frame rate of the simulation or just time itself. Also is there a way to set the starting zoom since the default is too zoomed in.
Currently my code looks like

```
meshcat.Delete()
meshcat.ResetRenderMode()
MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
```

For the zoom I tried Set2DRenderMode but then it no longer looks 3D.

Answer (score 0):

If your simulation is too fast, then there are at least two options:

1. You can use `simulator.set_target_realtime_rate()` to slow down the actual simulation.
2. You can have meshcat record the simulation, then use the recording sliders in the meshcat gui to play it back at whatever speed you like.  e.g. using

```
meshcat_visualizer.StartRecording()
simulator.AdvanceTo(...)
meshcat_visualizer.PublishRecording()
```

I would strong recommend option 2.

It's also possible to set the initial camera angle in 3D, but it's not intuitive.  You will be calling `meshcat.SetTransform()` in Drake on the appropriate camera transforms: you can read about the relationship between those transforms and the camera in the [meshcat documentation](https://github.com/rdeits/meshcat/tree/978cb8f519f9bb540e94b7f97a39ada4d7916b7c#camera-control).

Answer (score 0):

For option 2 that Russ mentioned, after `meshcat.PublishRecording()`, you will see the following menu in MeshCat.  Use `timeScale = 0.1` or `0.01` to playback 0.1X or 0.01X slower, without having to run your code again.

[image]